# How to use MVC (.NET 4.5) url routes instead if url parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Using ASP MVC, I have the following Action  link,

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Page", "Content", new { publicationId = publication.PublicationId })">@publication.Title</a>
```

for the controller action

```
public ActionResult Page(int publicationId)
```

Which works, but the URL looks like this

```
Content/Page?publicationId=129
```

and I prefer it to look like

> Content/Page/129

Is there anyway to make that change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a route to use your `publicationId` parameter for your `Content` controller
In your `App_Start\RouteConfig.cs` add above the `Default` route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ContentPage",
    url: "Content/{action}/{publicationId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Page", publicationId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If you want it to be specific only to the `Page` action:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ContentPage",
    url: "Content/Page/{publicationId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Content", action = "Page", publicationId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: publicationId is likely not optional in this case.